# Retrieving boolean from asynchronous function inside FileReader onload

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get the value of `x.includes("Encrypt")` from the following code (because I need to trigger some events depending on that value). If I do it using useState, I have an extra asynchronicity that just delays the events I want to trigger.

```
    const checkPDFProtection = (file) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        reader.onload = function () {

            var files = new Blob([reader.result], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            var result = files.text().then(x => {
                return x.includes("Encrypt") // --> the value I want to get
            });

            return result

        }
       
    }
```

I've seen solutions using callback functions and promises, but nothing seem to extract the value straight from the onload function.

Comment: don't mix callbacks and promises. no longer use the legacy filereader, use `const str = await file.text()` or `const ab = await file.arrayBuffer()`. it's wasteful to recreate a blob after you just have read it as an arraybuffer